# A math puzzle about slow clock

Tags: logic, intuition, puzzle

You have the misfortune to own an unreliable clock. This one loses exactly 20 minutes every hour. It is now showing 4:00am and you know that is was correct at midnight, when you set it. The clock stopped 4 hours ago, what is the correct time now?

OK.. I did really solve it. However, my solution was simple:
to literally write the time while an hour is 40min opposite to time when an hour is just an hour, 60 mins:

12:40 -          1 AM
1:20  -           2
2:00  -           3
2:40  -           4
3:20  -           5
4:00 AM-          6:00AM

and then add 4 hours so the answer is 10:00 AM.

Now another solution goes like this:

Since the clock is losing 20 minutes every hour, for every real hour that has passed, the clock will only show 40 minutes. Since the clock shows 4:00am, we know that 240 clock minutes have passed. **This therefore equals 360 real minutes and hence 6 hours.** The clock stopped 4 hour ago and the time must now be 10:00am.

Assumably, you could do 240:40 = 6 and there you go.. 6 additional hours to 12 AM.

What I don't understand is why divide 240 by 40?
240 mins reflect the "real" time when an hour is 60 minutes, why divide it by "40 minutes hour"?

Comment: 40 is two thirds of 60, so you're multiplying 240 by the inverse of $2/3$ (namely $3/2$)

Comment: I recommend giving this a more descriptive title, perhaps "a math puzzle about a slow clock".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quantity "$240$ minutes" describes the amount of time shown on the clock.
Since we know the clock is inaccurate, these "$240$ minutes"
do *not* reflect "real" time.  They reflect "clock" time.

$40$ minutes of "clock" time elapse in one hour of real time.
So $40n$ minutes of "clock" time is $n$ hours of real time.
Letting $240 = 40n$, we want to solve for $n$. 
What is the first step in solving that equation?

---

An alternative approach is: since the clock records only $\frac23$ hour
for each hour of real time that passes, it takes $\frac32$ hour of
real time for the clock to advance one hour.
For the clock to advance $m$ hours takes $\frac32 m$ real hours.
Since the clock advanced four hours, set $m = 4.$
But as noted in a comment, this is really doing the same thing,
just in a slightly different order of computation and using different units.

Comment: Thanks for the input..

I still don't understand why would you do 40*n? and why would the equation be 40n = 240? 
 I just don't get is why would we multiply 40 (clock hour) by n (number of real time hours)?

Comment: And how could I calculate that it takes 3/2 hour of real time for the clock to advance one hour?

I am not trolling..

Comment: There are never 40 clock hours; there's just a conversion factor which is 40 clock minutes per real hour. Kind of like how there are 100 centimeters per meter. To convert x meters to centimeters: (x m) * (100 cm/m) = 100x cm. Similarly, (n real hours) * (40 clock minutes/real hour) = 40n clock minutes.

Comment: Then there are the conversion factors in the other direction: if we have 100 cm/m then it's 0.01 m/cm to convert from centimeters back to meters, because 1/(100) = 0.01. 40 clock-minutes/real-hour is 2/3 clock-hours/real-hour, so the conversion factor for clock-hours to real hours is 3/2 real-hours/clock-hour.